# Maximizing concurrency when resizing image files in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Lets say I have a multi-threaded application that needs to resize some image files. I don't want multiple thread to be able to resize the same image at the same time and overwrite each others result and corrupt the file, but to maximise concurrency I do want multiple threads to be able to resize different images at the same time.

What would be the best approach for a thread to acquire a lock on a specific image rather than simply synchronizing an entire block of code?

Comment: Its pretty vague what you mean by "image" here. The file? An instance of Image in the heap?

Comment: I'm guessing he means on the heap

Comment: I mean files, ultimately I don't want Thread A to overwrite Thread B's result before A is finished and corrupt the file. I will modify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use an fixed thread `ExecutorService` and have a thread which submits all of the images into the service to be processed.  As long as you don't submit the same image twice you won't have a problem.
- You could also have a thread which feeds the "todo" `BlockingQueue` for the other threads to consume.  So then you have one thread that controls which images the threads work on so there would be no locks necessary.
- Another way to do it would be to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` and have each thread `putIfAbsent` and then only consume the image only if it worked.

  ```
  if (concurrentMap.putIfAbsent(imagePath, null) == null) {
     // do the processing
     // either remove it from map when done or leave it to stop future processing
  }
  // I guess loop around and look at the next image
  ```

Comment: I won't have control over the threads that request an image to be resized, I just know there will be lots of them. So I think the only way then is to use the ConcorrentHashMap technique. 

This was already what I was thinking so you have validated that for me.

Comment: if you insist on going multithreaded, I'd do 1 or 3; 2 is not scalable. Arguably 1 doesn't scale well either.

Comment: Why is #2 not scalable @Adrian?  That's approximately what the `ExecutorService` is doing.

Comment: #2 the thread which feeds the TODO queue becomes a bottle neck (unless I'm not understanding your statement). Executor with pool of threads is pretty much in the same category too, depending on how good their implementations is. The reason is the same why producer-consumer models don't scale: 1 bottle neck-the queue

Comment: Sorry but I disagree @Adrian.  That method _has_ to be more efficient then all of the threads polling a directory for files to process.  Image processing is going to be CPU intensive so the thread scheduling the work should never be the bottleneck.

Comment: No need to be sorry. I just saw he replied to my comment that the images are read from files not from memory. This gives me even more reason to enforce a single to read images and 1 for processing. I doubt resizing an image takes longer than HDD latency to seek for files. I'll edit my post now to include this case. I never said all threads polling a directory. That's just wrong. ;)

Answer (score -1):

- If images are in memory and you have 1 CPU, use **1 thread** only. No point in context switching between threads since there is no blocked waiting or other delays.
- If you have n CPU's, you can use 1 thread/CPU.
- If your images are located on different drives, something like RAID, you can use 1 thread/drive to load them in parallel, and 1 thread which does the resizing. You can use the producer consumer paradigm.

**EDIT: just saw the reply to my comment**
 - Since images are files on disk use **1 thread to read from disk the images** and **1 thread for processing**. Assuming resizing an image does not take longer than HDD latency to seek for files and load them in.